# IIS 10.0 redirect or rewrite from X domain to X domain with subdirectory

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

Kindly ask you for your help. I have checked all topic and didn't find a solution.

I have to implement the next:

If a customer uses: 
**test.site.com** 
it should redirect to
**test.site.com/rdweb**
include all subfolders in rdweb, there can be aspx files, HTML, etc.

I have been trying with:

```
<rule name="RDWeb" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url=".*" negate="false" />
                     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^test.site.com$" />
                     </conditions>
                     <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.site.com/rdweb" /> 
</rule>
```

in 99% it makes a loop with redirects and a browser shows the error:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I very much appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: That's simply because you don't give this rule a condition to end, so it will keep redirecting https://test.site.com/rdweb to itself. Add another condition please, so that when you see rdweb in URL, don't redirect any more.

Answer (score 1):

Your website get too many redirects because https://test.site.com/rdweb still match your reidirect rule.
Please add a condition pattern to {URL} to restrict the redirection only happen to https://test.site.com/ or https://test.site.com.

```
   <rule name="RDWeb" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url=".*" negate="false" />
                     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^test.site.com$" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(/)?$" />
                     </conditions>
                     <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.site.com/rdweb" /> 
</rule>
```

Comment: I don't know how to say THANK YOU! It works! Be healthy and strong!

Comment: @AntonHibchenko I'm so glad the rule will help you. It is appreciated if you could accept it as answer.XD